# summarise() in R by specific observations

Tags: r, summary

I am trying to gather summary statistics of a variable (diffdays) when the variable "disease" is equal to Malaria.

My code for this is:

`summary(deathdata$diffdays, deathdata$disease == "Malaria")`

This doesn't seem to be working the way I'd like but am I close? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to your data but using the built-in `mtcars` data I would summarize `mpg` with `summary(mtcars$mpg)`. If I wanted to limit my summary to just those cars with six cylinders I'd subset the data in my call to `summary`: `summary(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6, ]$mpg)`.

Comment: Thank you @rdelrossi! I used what you did:

`summary(deathdata[deathdata$DISEASE == "Malaria",]$diffdays)`

It worked perfectly! Appreciate your help!